# How to print the Username of user with most posts

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, forum, mybb

I am working on my website (it's sort of a practice project) and I am trying to create a line on the home page that displays the User with the most posts on the Forums. The Forum is a MyBB forum, so everything is very easy to look at. I have the general idea of how to query information from SQL, and have even gotten the posts a few times, but getting the person with the most posts username has eluded me. Here is my current code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("host", "username", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Top User: ", SELECT username FROM `mybb_users` ORDER BY `mybb_users`.`postnum` DESC LIMIT 0, 30 ;
echo "Users Posts: ", SELECT MAX(postnum) FROM  `mybb_users` or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Now, I have been messing with this for an hour or so, I am a noob, so I have finally come here to ask of y'alls help. I used to have the "mysql_query" prefix in front of the queries but they're removed here as a last attempt. I'm trying to get it to be very simple and look like this:

> Top User: John Doe
>
> Posts: 2313

I like figuring things out for myself, and I see coding as a fun thing to do, but this is out of my league. I looked around but my feeble mind could not handle the other answers. I'm not sure what else to say other than thank you for your help!

Comment: dont ever put your credentials in your post.

Comment: I know, I had removed it before, but I accidently put it back before posting X(

Comment: I think you need to read up on how to perform queries against MySQL, as you don;t just write some SQL in your code and hope it some how runs a queries against the database and then outputs the results.  There are probably any number of examples of this in your currently MyBB code base that you can look at. Normally, I would also reocmmend not using `mysql_*` functions, but if that is what is used throughout the existing code base, then is probably best to keep it consistent.

Comment: the credentials stay in the SO version control..so better change the pw ;)

Comment: Thank you Mark, it probably should of crossed my mind to explore the code of the Forums! Redreggae, I don't know what those abbreviations mean :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
 SELECT username, postnum FROM mybb_user ORDER BY postnum DESC LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT username, count(username) as postCount FROM mybb_posts GROUP BY username ORDER BY postCount DESC limit 1
```

**NOTE Do not use mysql* extension** At very least use mysqli, but preferably PDO I am just showing it to you since that what you are using

```
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT username, postnum FROM mybb_user ORDER BY postnum DESC LIMIT 1');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    echo $row['username'] . $row['postnum'];
```

Comment: It returns the USERID only for some reason, however, it gets me what I want when I run it in phpmyadmin. Thanks for this i'm getting closer!

Comment: Sometimes it also prints "resource id #11" or #12

Comment: Okay, basically I have no idea what i'm doing.

Comment: Sorry, I think my whole entire formatting has to go. As to not waste anymore time i'm just going to do more of my own research, and put a pin in this for now.